# android browser timers when keyboard is open

Tags: android, ajax, asynchronous, xmlhttprequest

I have run into this issue where asynchronous functions do not execute when the soft keyboard is open in the android browser.

For example:

```
<input type='text' id='foo'/>
....
document.getElementById("foo").addEventListener("keyup", function() {
window.setTimeout(function() { alert("1"); }, 20);
}, false);
```

You will never see the alert as long as you remain focused on the text input. This is true for xhr callbacks as well. If you attempt to make an ajax request, the request is sent, but the oncomplete callback is never fired until after you type another character in the textbox.

Does anyone know a workaround? You can see that Google obviously has a working example with their search suggestions, though I've not yet been able to figure out what exactly their solution is yet by looking at the minified/obfuscated source.

Any insight appreciated, Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Using the newest jquery lib in the style of

```
$("#inputnum").keyup(function(e){
  if (e.keyCode != '13') {
    $("#outputarea").slideUp('slow');
  };
});
```

causes the item selected with "#outputarea" to be slid up every time - as soon as I type any letter on the software keyboard or a hardware keyboard. Might want to give the jquery lib a shot? Cross-browser compatibility is the main reason I keep going back to it.